# Flink: Syncronize/connect two streams

Tags: scala, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have two streams, the first, with CEP library, it´s used it to detect patterns ON-OFF. In the second stream are values that I have to add. I'm looking for way to connect the two streams, so that when I receive an OFF frame, I return the device status change, with the ultimate value of the sum of the second type of frames:

```
Device 311 State Change:Ignition OFF  Value:35.91
```

My code:

```
// IGNITION pattern
val ig = timedValue.filter(_._2 == "Ignition").keyBy(_._4)
val patternIG_ON: Pattern[(Long,String,String,Long), _] = Pattern.begin[(Long,String,String,Long)]("start").where(_._3 == "OFF").next("end").where(_._3 == "ON")
val patternStream: PatternStream[(Long,String,String,Long)] = CEP.pattern(ig, patternIG_ON)
val patternIG_OFF: Pattern[(Long,String,String,Long), _] = Pattern.begin[(Long,String,String,Long)]("start").where(_._3 == "ON").next("end").where(_._3 == "OFF")
val patternStreamIG_OFF: PatternStream[(Long,String,String,Long)] = CEP.pattern(timedValue, patternIG_OFF)

def selectFn(pattern : mutable.Map[String,(Long,String,String,Long)]): String = {
  val startEvent = pattern.get("start").get
  val endEvent = pattern.get("end").get
  "Device "+startEvent._4 +" State Change: "+startEvent._2+" ON"
}
def selectFnOFF(pattern : mutable.Map[String,(Long,String,String,Long)]): String = {
  val startEvent = pattern.get("start").get
  val endEvent = pattern.get("end").get
  "Device "+startEvent._4 +" State Change: "+startEvent._2+" OFF "
}

val patternStreamSelected = patternStream.select(selectFn(_)).print()
val suma: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[(Long, Double)] = odo.map(s => (s._4,s._3)).keyBy(_._1).mapWithState(
  (in, state: Option[(Int, Double)]) => state match {
    case Some((count, sum)) => ((in._1,(sum + in._2).toDouble), Some((count + 1, sum + in._2)))
    case None => ((in._1, in._2), Some(1, in._2))
  })
val patternStreamSelectedOFF = patternStreamIG_OFF.select(selectFnOFF(_)).connect(suma).keyBy(_._1, _._1).map(l => l + " Value:", r => r._2).print()
```

**Update**: My Result:

```
24.2
23.5
44.010000000000005
67.05000000000001
Device 311 State Change3:Ignition ON
(311,Device 311 State Change: Ignition OFF ) Value:
```

the first number (24.2) is from another device, it should not appear...

Any idea what is the best approach??
Thank you